# How to filter CharField with Q-object as numeric

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-q

I have a database where the attribute I want to filter is given as a CharField.

The attibute contains numeric values as strings. e.g. '5.0'

I want to perform "less than" filtering (<) based on the numberic value of the string attibute, using Django Q-objects, so for example I want to get the rows in wich the attribute is less than 3.0.

I know about the a solution with the "extra" function, but as far as I know, "extra" won't take a Q-object as attribute.

Any idea about this?

Comment: Is there a serious reason to keep decimal values in CharField?

Comment: Yes, the database stores name-value pairs about mobile phone parameters, like name:"3G", value: "yes", name:"camera Mpx", value: "4" and so on, mostly string values, and I cannot change this structure, my client owns it.

Answer (score 0):

Does the "less than" filter work on CharField?

```
.filter(myfield__lt=3.0)
```

I know this isn't a Q() solution but perhaps it could be useful if supported.